# Java OutofBoundException in Array

Tags: java

I got this error. Though it may be very basic. 
I have declared array of length 3. Why does it still show an OutofBoundException error ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i;
            String[] arr = new String[3];
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the name");
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                arr[i] = input.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at arraysPractice.Arr2.main(Arr2.java:21)
```

Comment: the index is from 0, so when the length of array is 3 then index of them is:0 ,1,2

Answer (score 3):

It's because after completion of for loop, your `i` will be 3. Which is outOfBound because your array size is `3` only.

so print

```
System.out.println(arr[i-1]);
```

if you want to print last element.

**NOTE**

To avoid this type of errors, try using `arr[arr.lenght - 1]` to print last element.

Comment: you can accept the answer by pressing small right below voting button, if it solved your problem. :) @user2863083

Answer (score 0):

The loop is terminated with `i` having the value of `3`. You then try to print `arr[i]`, which won't work, since it only has the indexes `0`, `1` and `2`.

I'm guessing you meant to have the `System.out.println` statement **inside** the loop instead of after it?

Answer (score 0):

first iteration). I=0 and 0<3 so it goes into for loop and after that I++ so I=1.
second iteration).I=1 and 1<3 so it goes into for loop and after that I++ so I=2.
third iteration)I=2 and 2<3 so it goes into for loop and after that I++ so I=3
fourth iteration)I=3 and 3<3(false) it will exit loop and after that u are you are trying to print.  System.out.println(arr[i]);where I=3.   and your array size=3(means max position can be 2 and remaining positions are (0,1,2)) so it is index out of bound as you want to check array with index 3 but array max index is 2.

So QUICK fix put System.out.println(arr[i]); in for loop.